# Banco de dados , evento ou rotina ? daria certo?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Sou novo em criar evento e rotinas no banco de dados e me surgiu uma duvida estou fazendo um sistema de pagamento e queria saber se e possível colocar essa função como um evento ou uma rotina o codigo seria mas ou menos assim

```
    select idvencedordesafiante as vencedordesafiado,idvencedordesafiado as vencedordesafiante,valor as receber,id as idp from partidas where aceitou=2
if(vencedordesafiado==vencedordesafiante){

UPDATE `usuarios` SET `Saldo`=receber WHERE id= vencedordesafiado
UPDATE `partidas` SET `aceitou`=3 WHERE id= idp
}
```

alguem que entende mais saberia me disser se daria certo ?

Comment: Sim seria possível, se quiser um exemplo prático, informe qual o seu banco de dados (Firebird, MySQL, SQL Server....)

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro, Mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um Trigger para a sua tabela, como abaixo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `partidas_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `partidas` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  if(new.aceitou = 2)then
    if(new.idvencedordesafiante = new.idvencedordesafiado){
      UPDATE 'usuarios' SET 'Saldo' = new.valor WHERE id = new.idvencedordesafiado
      UPDATE 'partidas' SET 'aceitou' = 3 WHERE id = new.id
     end if;
  end if;
END
```

Esse é apenas um exemplo, pode ter um errinho ou outro, procure entender e aplicar corretamente pro seu caso.

Mas criei um exemplo de uma trigger na sua tabela partidas, onde vai ser executada sempre que um registro for incluído na mesma.

**O que é uma trigger?**

> Um TRIGGER ou gatilho é um objeto de banco de dados, associado a uma
>   tabela, definido para ser disparado, respondendo a um evento em
>   particular. Tais eventos são os comandos da DML (Data Manipulation
>   Language): INSERT, REPLACE, DELETE ou UPDATE. Podemos definir inúmeros
>   TRIGGERS em uma base de dados baseados diretamente em qual dos
>   comandos acima irá dispará-lo, sendo que, para cada um, podemos
>   definir apenas um TRIGGER. Os TRIGGERS poderão ser disparados para
>   trabalharem antes ou depois do evento.

Você pode ler mais algumas coisas sobre triggers(Gatilhos) [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-basico-triggers/37462) e [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-triggers/8088)

**EDITADO**

Conforme você pediu nos comentários, fiz este exemplo de um Event Scheduler para executar os updates que quer:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `partidas`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2018-10-01 13:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT ''
DO BEGIN
  select @vencedordesafiado  := coalesce(idvencedordesafiante, 0)
        ,@vencedordesafiante := coalesce(idvencedordesafiado, 0)
        ,@receber            := coalesce(valor, 0)
        ,@idp                := coalesce(id, 0)
   from partidas where aceitou = 2

  if(@idp <> 0)then
    if(@vencedordesafiado = @vencedordesafiante)
      UPDATE 'usuarios' SET 'Saldo' = @receber WHERE id = @vencedordesafiante
      UPDATE 'partidas' SET 'aceitou' = 3 WHERE id = @idp
     end if;
  end if;
END
```

Obs.: Montei o exemplo usando `limit 1` para trazer apenas uma linha no select, então você terá que ajeitar seu filtro ou fazer um loop para ir passando linha a linha.

Novamente, é um exemplo, então melhore-o de acordo com suas necessidades e altere o horário de inicio do evento para uns minutos depois de você cria-lo para executar corretamente.

Você pode dar uma lida sobre eventos [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/quick-tips-habilitando-e-entendendo-events-no-mysql-parte-1/14018)

Comment: isso so funcionaria quando tivesse uma alteração no banco de dados ne?, teria como eu fazer ele executar a cada 30 segundo ou 1 minuto altomaticamente?

Comment: Isso, esse exemplo seria para quando existisse um INSERT, UPDATE ou DELETE, mas da para executar de tempo em tempo, vou montar um exemplo e logo estarei editando minha resposta.

Comment: nossa mano, muito obg